# Assignments in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, variable-assignment, symbolic-math, sparse-array

Question about assignments and variables

```
(* For example *) SP = SparseArray[{},5] or SP = Range[5]
```

now we want to work with this array in some another function :

```
(* example *) Fun[array_]:= array[[3]] = 100 ; (* set cell №3 equal to 100*)
```

then we eval

```
Fun[SP]
```

**ERROR!** output will be an Error like: **`Set::write Tag SparseArray in ... is Protected.`**

So what is the right way to change the arguments of function in function (non-pure-functions)? How to creare analog-like of **`Part[]`**?

maybe smth like:

```
Clear[f]; f[a_]:=Set[Symbol[a][[3]],100]; A =SparseArray[{},5]; f["A"];
```

But it's error again

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! there is a new StackExchange site dedicated to Mathematica which might be of interest to you. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am certain this is a duplicate question but I am feeling lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Chris Degnen's method should generally be avoided.
*Mathematica* provides a better way: [the Hold attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html).

```
a = Range[5];

SetAttributes[fun, HoldFirst]

fun[array_] := array[[3]] = 100

fun[a];

a
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 100, 4, 5}
> ```

As a "pure function":

```
b = Range[5];

fun2 = Function[array, array[[3]] = 100, HoldFirst];

fun2[b];

b
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 100, 4, 5}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SP = Range[5];
Fun[array_] := array[[3]] = 100;(*set cell №3 equal to 100*)
Fun[Unevaluated@SP];
SP
```

{1, 2, 100, 4, 5}